# Need Regular Expression for the password in my angular application

Tags: regex

Need Regex Expression for the following password conditions:
1 capital, 1 lower case, 1 special character, 1 numeric, no characters other then alphanumeric and special characters, minimum length of 8, max length of 30

Comment: "no characters other then alphanumeric and special characters ... max length of 30" -- Why? Don't impose arbitrary password restrictions.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What difficulty/errors have you encountered? StackOverflow is a place to ask questions about your code, not a place to get others to write it all for you.

Comment: Can you come up with positive and negative examples? And then, at least something that doesn't work just yet.

Comment: You should read [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it with lookaheads:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[+-_*%#!$/\\"'`])[a-zA-Z0-9+-_*%#!$/\\"'`]{4,30}$
```

Explanation:

- ``` ^[a-zA-Z0-9+-_*%#!$/\\"'``]{4,30}$ ``` restricts the length and the type of characters
- `(?=....)` is a lookahead
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` makes sure there is at lest one uppercase character
- `(?=.*[0-9])` makes sure there is at least one number
- and so on, the other two lookaheads are for lower case chars and special chars

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/rSHLMP/1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer